# How to override dynamoDB data using Glue job

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-glue

As I understand, Joob Bookmarks prevents the duplicated data. "Enable" updates the data based on the previous data, and "disable" process the entire dataset (does this mean it overrides it? I tried this, but the job took for too long and i'm not sure if it does what i think it does.)

But what if I want to override the Dynamodb Table in the job? I've seen examples where the output data is in S3, but I'm not sure about the DynamoDB.

For example I have a Glue job like this:

```
import sys
from awsglue.transforms import *
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.job import Job

args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ["JOB_NAME"])
sc = SparkContext()
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
spark = glueContext.spark_session
job = Job(glueContext)
job.init(args["JOB_NAME"], args)

# Script generated for node Redshift Cluster
RedshiftCluster_node1 = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(
    database="tr_bbd",
    redshift_tmp_dir=args["TempDir"],
    table_name="tr_bbd_vendor_info",
    transformation_ctx="RedshiftCluster_node1",
)

# Script generated for node ApplyMapping
ApplyMapping_node2 = ApplyMapping.apply(
    frame=RedshiftCluster_node1,
    mappings=[
        ("vendor_code", "string", "vendor_code", "string"),
        ("vendor_group_id", "int", "vendor_group_id", "int"),
        ("vendor_group_status_name", "string", "vendor_group_status_name", "string")
    ],
    transformation_ctx="ApplyMapping_node2",
)

# Script generated for node DynamoDB bucket
Datasink1 = glueContext.write_dynamic_frame_from_options(
    frame=ApplyMapping_node2,
    connection_type="dynamodb",
    connection_options={
        "dynamodb.output.tableName": "VENDOR_TABLE",
        "dynamodb.throughput.write.percent": "1.0"
    }
)
job.commit()
```

Thank you.

Comment: So Glue job override the data if it exists in the table, but what if the data isn't in the input data anymore? Does the Glue job delete the data from the dynamodb table if it's not in the input data anymore?

Answer (score 0):

When writing data, the Item with the same Key (Hash Key & Range Key) will be overwritten, otherwise it will be newly written and the existing Item will not be affected.
If you want to overwrite entire table, need use boto3 to delete items in the table first.